# In php urls, can I use something like ?name=Item+Name?

Tags: php, url, dynamic

The site I manage uses php urls to show a detail.php dynamically for each product (still new to php, please bear with me).

the currently look like this:

```
domain.com/detail.php?id=123
```

can I use a different attribute (not sure if that's what it's called) so I can have slightly more user friendly urls?

Like:

```
domain.com/detail.php?name=Product+Name
```

and if so... how? for the life of me I can't figure it out or search for the right terms (probably just don't know their correct names yet). I figured it would be simple as a %20 instead of the spaces, but as you all probably know, this doesn't do it.

I have name set to varchar, and I have no idea if that makes a difference.

any help is appreciated, this isn't an urgent thing.

Comment: Can you show the code that generates this URL?

Comment: <a href="detail.php?id=<?php echo $row_featuredItems['id']; ?>">

just an example of a featured item list url

Comment: And that doesn't work for you, just the way it is, leaving the space there just as a space and not encoding or decoding it?

Comment: i wish i could say i completely understand your question.

when I do it the same way replacing 'id' with 'name' and id= with name= all the spaces go to %20's, and the content is empty

Comment: Take a look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10419979/259457) below.

Comment: not entirely sure what I did... but Marc B put me on the right track. working now.

thanks for all the quick suggestions!

*edit* it was actually marc and travesty that knew what was happening. thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm really not sure where you're having trouble. This very basic example works just fine for me:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET["name"]))
        die("name = {$_GET["name"]}");    /* outputs "name = Product Name" */

    $row = "Product Name";
?><a href="test.php?name=<?php echo $row; ?>">Click here</a>
```

Comment: I can get the product name to output into the url fine, I think Marc B knows the problem, it's with my query on my detail page i think.

Answer (score 6):

There's a few different methods of accomplishing what you want. Without digging straight into the PHP code to change the underlying logic you could have a look at enabling and configuring mod_rewrite within your Apache implementation. Here's a quick and simple mod_rewrite tutorial:

http://www.htmlist.com/how-to/a-simplemod_rewrite-tutorial/

Comment: I've been combing throughout all the mod_rewrite tutorials out there, and I figured that'd be the next step.

Wouldn't it be a simpler mod_rewrite rule if the url already had the product name in it?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the functions to work with URLs in PHP: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.url.php.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the PHP-method [`urlencode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) to encode a string so that it can be passed as a querystring-variable. You can then user [`urldecode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) to decode the querystring-variable.

Comment: so, would something like this work?

<?php echo '<a href="detail.php?name=', urlencode($ $row_featuredItems['name']), '">'; ?>

Comment: @paul_the_dino Yes, something like that. This would probably work `<?php echo '<a href="detail.php?name=' . urlencode($row_featuredItems['name']) . '">'; ?> `

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not building your query right, and that'd mean you're vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Retrieving a string value from a query is no different than retrieving an integer, but how you use that string later on DOES make a huge difference:

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
$safe_name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
$sql = "SELECT ... FROM yourtable WHERE name='$safe_name'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die($sql);
```

When using strings in queries, they MUST be enclosed with quotes. If they're not, they're treated as field names, table names, etc...